# Border inside a Grid containing GridSplitter-s overlaps all following rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Using WPF I'm trying to create a Grid which contains A list view then some controller with details and then a row with a singe button. Here's what I tried

```
<Grid DataContext="...">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="177" MinHeight="177"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0"  BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="SomeName"/>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Height="Auto" Padding="1">
        <ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="1" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource someTemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding itemBinding, Mode=OneWay}" Height="Auto"/>
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3"  Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="4"  Grid.RowSpan="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="3,0,0,0" Command="{Binding Click}" Width="28" Height="28" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{StaticResource Heart}"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The above XAML is functional but the border overlaps all rows below and including row 2, instead of going just up to the next `GridSplitter`.

And it looks roughly like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have five rows but only three row definitions

Add the desired row definitions:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="177" MinHeight="177"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and the layout should be correct.

Comment: That makes total sense, although for the love of everything it's kind of something I'd think the IDE can actually suggest :)